# android Annotation Syntax

Tags: android, android-resources, android-annotations

I know this is stupid question But

I have never used `android Annotation`, it just appeared with auto-complete in android studio and I thought its a good idea to use it, I'm I right?

I did my research and I learned how to use it with `parameters` but I didn't find anything about how to use it with `pair` and `generic`

here is my code

```
private Pair<StringRes ,DrawableRes> getRespectiveStingAndDrawableRes(String permission) {
        if(permission.equals(Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE))
            return Pair.create(R.string.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE_permision_message,R.drawable.ic_menu_gallery);
        return null;
    }
```

and this error appeared

```
Error:(49, 31) error: incompatible types
required: Pair<StringRes,DrawableRes>
found:    Pair<Integer,Integer>
```

i tried to use `IntegerRes` but also not worked

note: the `piar` I used is  `android.support.v4.util.Pair`

Comment: Is `R.string.bla_bla_bla` not `StringRes`?

Comment: No, it's an integer id that points to a string resource. StringRes is an annotation class, not a String object class

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot use these annotations that way. They are mainly used to limit parameter values to a given type, e.g. `@StringRes` requires that the specified `int` value is a valid string resource.

For this `Pair` you still have to write `Integer`, since that is the actual variable type:

```
private Pair<Integer, Integer> getRespectiveStingAndDrawableRes(String permission) {
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure how your question relates to annotations, since you don't use any, but the error points to the fact that `R.string` and `R.drawable` both are int values, and not StringRes or DrawableRes

This might work. Note `@XRes` is the annotation, it's not a class type like you are trying to use it as.

```
private Pair<Integer , Integer> getRespectiveStingAndDrawableRes(String permission) {
        if(permission.equals(Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE))
            return Pair.create(@StringRes R.string.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE_permision_message, @DrawableRes R.drawable.ic_menu_gallery);
        return null;
    }
```

And if that doesn't work, then just remove the two `@XRes` annotations

Comment: Error:annotations are not allowed here (inside method Pair.create)

Comment: Like I said, it might work, meaning maybe not. Just get rid of the annotations, then.  Here is a link on actually using them correctly.  https://github.com/excilys/androidannotations/wiki/Resources